# How to prepend URLs with a default protocol if it's absent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9. A my model class has a `link` attribute and, before to store related objects in to the database, I would like to prepend that value (a URL, kind of strings) with a default protocol *if* it's absent (example protocols can be `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://`, `ftps://` and so on; the default one is `http://`). In order to make that I am thinking to implement a Rails callback with some regex and maybe by using the [URI Ruby library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), but I am in trouble on how to implement that.

Any idea? How can / should I make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a before_validation callback is likely where you want to start

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  PROTOCOLS = ["http://", "https://", "ftp://", "ftps://"]
  validates_format_of :website, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https ftp ftps))
  before_validation :ensure_link_protocol

  def ensure_link_protocol
    valid_protocols = ["http://", "https://", "ftp://", "ftps://"]
    return if link.blank?
    self.link = "http://#{link}" unless PROTOCOLS.any?{|p| link.start_with? p}
  end

end
```

Comment: Since you use `URI.regexp` to determine validness, I'd suggest you use that library to find the protocol too: `self.link = "http://#{website}" if PROTOCOLS.include? URI.parse(link).scheme`. PROTOCOLS should then be `w%{http https ftp ftps}` and can be re-used in the `:with => RI::regexp(PROTOCOLS)` too.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using a simple regex substitution?

```
class String
  def ensure_protocol
    sub(%r[\A(?!http://)(?!https://)(?!ftp://)(?!ftps://)], "http://")
  end
end

"http://foo".ensure_protocol # => "http://foo"
"https://foo".ensure_protocol # => "https://foo"
"ftp://foo".ensure_protocol # => "ftp://foo"
"ftps://foo".ensure_protocol # => "ftps://foo"
"foo".ensure_protocol # => "http://foo"
```